# How to 'order by' prepared select statement without making a second search

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-order-by, prepared-statement

Is there a way to order the prepared sql without preparing another select?

```
$stmt = $conexao->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_codigo = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",  $usu_codigo);
$stmt->execute();
```

I wanna get the data from `usu_datacadastro` and then order:

```
SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_indicador_codigo = ? ORDER BY usu_datacadastro DESC LIMIT 5
```

But I already have this data provided by the first sql, I just need to do the order by and echo somewhere.

Comment: use usort function

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, something like this might help you http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
usort(
  $data,
  function($arr1, $arr2) { 
      // descending 
      return strcmp($arr2['usu_datacadastro'], $arr1['usu_datacadastro']);
  });
```

If you want to preserve the original order of the array, I would suggest adding pointers/references to an array in the order you desire, as opposed to cloning the array.

Comment: To be honest, I'm completely lost with this function, I'm new into prepared statements, so that complicates everything a little bit, can you help me with the syntax? I have saw these kinds of sorts and they make comparisons between arrays and all, I would really appreciate some help with the syntax.

Comment: Assuming $data is the name of the array holding the data from the DB and usu_datacadastro is a key in each subsequent array, this will sorry $data how you are asking. Have you tried swapping $data for your array? I’m not at a computer to test it

Comment: @LuannSousa This has nothing to do with prepared statements. It's just using PHP's sorting method instead of doing it in SQL.

Comment: @atoms yes, I tried with the following code:

$query="SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_codigo = $usu_codigo";

$usu_info_array_result = $conexao->query($query);
$row = $usu_info_array_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
usort(
  $usu_info_array_result,
  function($arr1, $arr2) { 
      // descending 
      return strcmp($arr2['usu_datacadastro'], $arr1['usu_datacadastro']);
  });

Comment: it says that I'm giving a object instead of an array, but, didn't I made the conversion with this code?

Comment: oh wait, I gave the wrong var, I have changed fro $rowin usort, but it returns me Illegal string offset 'usu_datacadastro'

Comment: whats the output of `var_dump($rowin)`? The illegal offset means that the key isnt present in the array.
the structure should look something like this:

`0 => array('usu_datacadastro' => 'foo', 'field2' => 'bar'),
1 => array('usu_datacadastro' => 'foo', 'field2' => 'bar'),`